# How to count the no. of same strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe like:

```
Company Date        Country
ABC     2017-09-17   USA
BCD     2017-09-16   USA
ABC     2017-09-17   USA
BCD     2017-09-16   USA
BCD     2017-09-16   USA
```

I want to get a resultant df as :

```
Company  No: of Days
ABC      2
BCD      3
```

How do i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df['Company'].value_counts()
                   .rename_axis('Company').reset_index(name='No: of Companies')
print (df1)
  Company  No: of Companies
0     BCD                 3
1     ABC                 2
```

Another solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Company').size().reset_index(name='No: of Companies')
print (df1)
  Company  No: of Companies
0     BCD                 3
1     ABC                 2
```

If need count `Date` columns:

```
df1 = df['Date'].value_counts().rename_axis('Date').reset_index(name='No: of Days')
print (df1)
         Date  No: of Days
0  2017-09-16            3
1  2017-09-17            2

df1 = df.groupby('Date').size().reset_index(name='No: of Days')
print (df1)
         Date  No: of Days
0  2017-09-16            3
1  2017-09-17            2
```

EDIT:

If need count pairs `Date` and `Company` columns:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Company']).size().reset_index(name='No: of Days per company')
print (df1)
         Date Company  No: of Days per company
0  2017-09-16     BCD                        3
1  2017-09-17     ABC                        2
```

Comment: you are not at all using the 'date' column ?

Comment: @MohanRaj - I add solutions for `date` column, but then output is different.

Comment: I want only a dataframe which has only 2 columns in the result - company and date

Comment: @MohanRaj - yes. But it depends you need count column `Company` or column `Date`s. If my solution is not what you need, can you change sample data and add desired output?

Comment: Sorry, the i erred in the comment section - i needed only 2 columns - company and no_of_days_per_company.

Comment: Super, then check last edit - nned groupby by both columns.

Comment: @StephenRauch - It depends ... :) But it seems generally yes... thanks.